# Adding vertical space without affecting the alignment of text

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

I would like to add some vertical space in my document without affecting the alignment and format of the sentences before the space.

What exactly I do is :

```
\cvsection{Education}
\textbf{Some text} \years{2010-Expected December 2012} \\ 
\vspace{1.5mm}
\textit{Sometext2}.\\
\textit{sometext3}
```

Now the output i get has an additional sapce before sometext2. It looks something like this:

```
Sometext
 Sometext2

Sometext3
```

As it can be seen the space gets added after sometext2 but there an extra space that is created before sometext2, Which I would like to remove. As i am working on my Resume, I would obviously like it to be perfect.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The space comes from the word space so you could remove it by using a `%` after the `\vspace` but really you don't want to be using `\vspace` mid-paragraph at all like this. You could use `\\[1.5mm]` to get a line break with extra space but why all the forced line breaks, this looks suspiciously as if it should be an itemized or description list of some sort.